# Check if list has been modified

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio, controls, panel

I'm trying to basically make a FlowLayoutPanel only accept a custom control that I've created that inherits a Button. So I've Shadowed the Controls property and I've created my own property, but instead of declaring it as a ControlsCollection, I've declared it as a list:

```
Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Controls() As ControlCollection
    Get
        Return MyBase.Controls
    End Get
End Property

Private itms As New List(Of MenuItem)
Public Property Items() As List(Of MenuItem)
    Get
        Return itms
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of MenuItem))
        itms = value
    End Set
End Property
```

What I'm stumped at is how check if the Items() property has been modified, that away I can call something like:

```
 Me.Controls.Clear : Me.Controls.AddRange(itms.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is that by exposing `Items`, stuff can be added to it, you could remove that and expose `AddItem` and `RemoveItem` type methods instead:

```
Private _dataChanged As Boolean = False
Public Function AddItem(ByVal mi As MenuItem) As Integer
    _items.Add(mi)
    _dataChanged = True
    return _items.Count
End Function
```

As a `List(Of T)` it prevents non T items from being added, but your control is not really fully in charge of the item list with exposed that way.  Another way might be to use a BindingList which includes a `ListChanged` event:

```
Private WithEvents _items As New BindingList(Of MenuItem)
Private _dataChanged As Boolean = False     ' maybe
AddHandler _items.ListChanged, AddressOf _listChanged

Public Property Items() As BindingList(Of MenuItem)
  Get
      Return itms
  End Get
  Set(value As List(Of MenuItem))
      _items = value
  End Set
End Property

'...

private Event _listChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
          ByVal e As ListChangedEventArgs)
    _dataChanged = True
    RoutineToDoSomethingAboutDataChanged()
End Sub
```

You can tell which item changed via `ListChangedEventArgs` so you can do something with just the changed item, if desired.  `Me.Controls.AddRange(itms.ToArray())` wont work because the BindingList does not support the `ToArray` method.

Also, whats the point of moving them to the ControlCollection?  Is that for serialization?